# Trying to make a UNIQUE KEY become a FOREIGN KEY, but it says error

Tags: postgresql

I created this table. I want the user_id to be inserted without someone having to type it. Can someone help me? When I tried to create it it shows this error:

[image]

Why is the fk_id being compared to cpf?

```
CREATE TABLE code.went_to  
(
    user_id INTEGER,
    cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    cep VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    date DATE,
    contact_id INTEGER,

    CONSTRAINT fk_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES code.user, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_cpf_user 
        FOREIGN KEY (cpf) REFERENCES code.user, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_cep_place 
        FOREIGN KEY (cep) REFERENCES code.place,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tipo_id 
        FOREIGN KEY (tipo_id) REFERENCES code.contact,
    EXCLUDE USING gist (cpf WITH =, cep WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '4 months')::date) WITH &&),
    EXCLUDE USING gist (cep WITH =, contact_id WITH =, daterange(data, (data + interval '1 months')::date) WITH &&) 
);
```

The table that `user_id` comes from:

```
CREATE TABLE code.user 
(
    user_id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    cpf VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    name CHAR(75) NOT NULL,
    nick_name VARCHAR(15),

    CONSTRAINT pk_cpf PRIMARY KEY(cpf),
    CONSTRAINT un_id UNIQUE (id),
    CONSTRAINT un_nick_name UNIQUE (nick_name)
);
```

Sorry if its stated weird, my English is not the best. But essentially the question should be:

How could I import data (`user_id`) from one table (`user`) into another table (`went_to`) based on the primary key (`cpf`)?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the error-message as text, not an image. These are a pain to read.

Comment: A foreign key refers to the primary key of the foreign table. The primary key of code.user is cpft, a varchar. It is curious that user has a unique ID and a separate primary key.

Comment: The primary key is the social security and the id its so I can type the id insted of the whole number all the time

Comment: Btw: `user` is a reserved keyword. You should try to find a different name, otherwise you'll run into a lot of problems.

Comment: @yellow_melro Make user_id the primary key and the cpf a unique key. Social security numbers can change! Consider the security implications of storing social security numbers. And consider more descriptive names than "cpf" and "cep".

Comment: How could I use a variable to import data (user_id) from one table (user) to another (went_to) based on the primary key (cpf)?

Comment: I am not actually using the term user. The name is participante_id (i just translated so is 
 easier to undertand the code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a target column, the `references` clause assumes the **primary key** of the target table. There is no matching on the name happening.

You need to include the column of the unique key in your foreign key definition:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES code."user"(user_id)
```

To make things less confusing, I would also do that for the FK that references the PK

```
CONSTRAINT fk_cpf_user FOREIGN KEY (cpf) REFERENCES code."user"(cpf),
```

Comment: I did it and it worked, but the id from the user is not being imported :(